# Practice Questions Apex

Tags: apex

I am learning Apex and want to practise questions especially about Maps,Lists and Loops
I am trying to write codes and real life questions
Can someone advise me where to find this kind of practise questions or provide me these questions?
Because resources are limited when it comes to Apex.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Personally, I think that https://www.sfdc99.com/beginner-tutorials/ is a fantastic resource for beginners. The PluralSight course - https://www.pluralsight.com/authors/david-liu - is also super helpful.

Answer (score 2):

All of the documentation and trailheads presume that you have some knowledge of programming already. I suggest you find a book such as *Java in 24 Hours, Sams Teach Yourself*, or something similar. If you already understand Java, Apex will become much easier to learn. Learning how programming works in general will lead you to be a much better Apex developer. You can also read the [Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm) from front to back, but I honestly think that you'd be better served with an introductory language before attempting Apex.